# Chamadas many to many no template

Tags: django

Gostaria de saber como fazer uma chamada no template para um campo *many to many* do models.

Segue código:

Models

```
class Projeto(models.Model):
professor_participante = models.ManyToManyField(Servidor,   verbose_name=u'Professores participante', blank=True)
```

Views

```
def projeto(request):
context={}
context['projeto'] = Projeto.objects.all()
return render(request, 'projeto.html', context)
```

template

```
{% for projetos in projeto %}
<li>Professor participante - {{ projetos.professor_participante }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tanto em relações muitos-para-muitos quanto em relações muitos-para-um, pode-se usá-las em um `for` através do sufixo `.all` (da mesma forma que você faria no código Python `proj.professor_participante.all()`, só que sem os parênteses ao final).

```
{% for projetos in projeto %}
    <ul>
    {% for professor in projetos.professor_participante.all %}
        <li>Professor participante - {{ professor.nome }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Aqui está [a documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/#accessing-method-calls) para a chamada de métodos dentro de um template. A única diferença é que nesse caso (many-to-many) basta usar o nome do campo, enquanto numa relação de um para muitos você teria que usar o nome da relação inversa (tipicamente `entidade_set` - a menos que você tenha lhe dado um nome próprio).

P.S. Por que você está chamando sua lista de `projeto` (no singular) e cada elemento individual de `projetos` (no plural)? Dei a resposta conforme a pergunta, mas o ideal seria trocar esses nomes.